# Does FAA part 91 require aircraft flight logs?

Tags: usa, logging, far-91, aircraft-ownership

What are the record-keeping requirements for flight or operational use of an aircraft only flown under Part 91? Rental aircraft always have such a logbook, for obvious reasons, but are privately-owned-and-operated aircraft required to keep such a log by regulation?

[91.417](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91/subpart-E/section-91.417) and [43.9](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-43/section-43.9) clearly dictate the requirements we often refer to as the **airframe, engine, and prop maintenance logs**. This is not the same as an aircraft flight log.

[AC 43-9C](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/22587) further clarifies the above.

[61.51](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.51) dictates **pilot experience** logging requirements. Some of the information recorded in a pilot log is duplicated in the aircraft flight log.

In Canada, this is referred to as a "journey log" and the requirements are explicitly stated in [605.94](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-96-433/page-77.html#h-996954)

[AC 91-70B](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1030086) concerns flying in "oceanic and remote continental airspace", but deep in 5.4.1.2 recommends a journey log and references ICAO Annex 6.

ICAO Annex 6 Part I 11.4 defines the "journey log" for commercial flights, and is a "recommendation".

ICAO Annex 6 Part II 2.8.2 similarly defines the "journey log" for general aviation, and is also a "recommendation".

Comment: I cannot find an open access reference to link to the ICAO Convention on International Civil Aviation. It appears to be a document that can be purchased for a fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Federal Aviation Regulation (14 CFR Part 91) that requires a "flight log" as described in your question.